# Detect team call with lync API

Tags: c#, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I developed a small application in C# which observers the Lync 2013 client for incoming calls. Some information about the caller and the type of call (sip, tel) is then processed for other purposes. But I have a problem with detecting e.g. team calls. I don't know which property I have to test for. But I need to distinguish between calls that are directly for myself and calls that are for someone else from my team.

Do you have any advice for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Microsoft calls this feature "call delegation".

Here are some links with further information on this topic:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933187.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933162.aspx
- https://rcosic.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/handling-transfers-in-lync-client-api/